# Android Studio - Reference plugin library

Tags: java, android, bcrypt

Evening all,

I am thoroughly ripping my hair our with this one, it's probably as basic as you can possibly imagine (as far as Android Studio goes anyway). Please forgive me if this is an extremely stupid question, however I am very new to Java and Android development.

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and have just downloaded and installed the Hash Generator plugin from Victor Alenkov to use the bcrypt function to hash a password etc.

I'm just trying to use a basic example pulled from their README doc:

```
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw("test", BCrypt.gensalt());
```

And Android Studio is returning:

```
Cannot Resolve Symbol 'BCrypt'
```

I cannot find any .jar file in my dir, nor can I find a dependency to reference for Hash Generator. I know I'm missing something very basic, and I've been googling for a while now, but have only come across a couple of threads that reference BCrypt and they are obviously well beyond the stage I am currently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you add the dependency to gradle?

Comment: A plugin for the IDE cannot be used in the code. If you want to use bcrypt hashing in your app, you'll need to add that library as dependency, not install a plugin for the android studio

Comment: I attempted to add a depenmdancy to gradle, but couldn't locate the .jar file for an actual reference name. Then I tried to put the .java file from a previous stackoverflow link instead, but it couldn't compile the java file. I couldn't find any libraries relating to bcrypt or Hash Geneartor when searching, only a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont have the library of the object "BCrypt"
you can get it here: http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/jBCrypt-0.2-doc/
And then add to your gradle in Android Studio like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar')
}
```

Then you can import the library to your java file in Android:

```
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
```

Now you can use the object BCrypt.

Take care.